# Get Shrove Tuesday in Lua

Tags: date, lua, calendar

How can I get the date of Shrove Tuesday (`12/02/2013`, `04/03/2014`, `17/02/2015`, etc.) in Lua from a supplied year? If possible, could it be explained clearly so that it can be adapted for Easter, Mother's Day, and other holidays that change each year? There are scripts available online that get Easter, but they're not explained very clearly and I don't understand how I can change them for Shrove Tuesday and other holidays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrove_Tuesday), Shrove Tuesday is exactly 47 days before Easter Sunday. So the key is really just how to calculate Easter Day, a movable feast. You can modify the [code to calculate Easter](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Calendar_script) to get Shrove Tuesday.

```
function shrove_tuesday(year)
    local leap_year
    if year % 4 == 0 then 
        if year % 100 == 0 then 
            if year % 400 == 0 then 
                leap_year = true
            else 
                leap_year = false 
            end
        else 
            leap_year = true 
        end
    else 
        leap_year = false
    end
    local a = year % 19
    local b = math.floor(year / 100)
    local c = year % 100
    local d = math.floor(b / 4)
    local e = b % 4
    local f = math.floor((b + 8) / 25) 
    local g = math.floor((b - f + 1) / 3)
    local h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30
    local i = math.floor(c / 4)
    local k = c % 4
    local L = (32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k) %7
    local m = math.floor((a + 11 * h + 22 * L) / 451)
    local month = math.floor((h + L - 7 * m + 114 - 47) / 31)
    local day = (h + L - 7 * m + 114 - 47) % 31 + 1
    if month == 2 then    --adjust dates in February 
        day = leap_year and day - 2 or day - 3
    end
    return day, month
end
```

The calculation seems complicated, that's because calculating Easter Day is complicated, this function is following the algorithm of [Computus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Meeus.2FJones.2FButcher_Gregorian_algorithm).

Test:

```
print(shrove_tuesday(2012))
print(shrove_tuesday(2013))
print(shrove_tuesday(2014))
print(shrove_tuesday(2015))
```

Output:

```
21      2
12      2
4       3
17      2
```

You can easily use the `day` and `month` to get formatted string using `string.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", day, month, year)` or whatever you need.

Comment: You can use `%` instead of `math.mod`.

Comment: @lhf You are right, now it's cleaner, I was following the code to calculate Easter.

Comment: @YuHao - `leap_year` is calculated but not used.  Adjusting dates in February must depend on leap year.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You are right, I missed that, the test was incomplete, I hate February :(